# In iTunes, is there way to switch easily back and forth between tracks in two different playlists or library parts (say podcast and music)?

Tags: itunes, music, podcasts, playlist

*Use case:* I often want to toggle between a podcast and a music playlist in iTunes. Say, while ironing I listen to a podcast, later when I do computer work I switch to music, then when unstacking the dish washer I want to go back to the podcast and after this, music is on again, etc, etc…

Is there a script or plugin for iTunes, which remembers **track**, **position** and **library/playlist**, so that I can switch back to it? Or is there another convenient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are referring to something like a Smart Playlist. Smart Playlists organizes your songs more, based upon song type, last listened to, skip count, etc.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1801

Comment: No it is not about smart playlists. It is about switching  from one library to another (or a playlist) and being able to switch _quickly_ back again.